# Why does this Javascript work in the browser console but not in Selenium's JavascriptExecutor?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath, javascript-injection

So I've been using the JavascriptExecutor class in my Selenium code because Javascript seems to handle DOM manipulation more gracefully than Selenium. I use XPaths to locate my elements and the way Javascript handles XPaths is with this line of code (note that 'xpath' is the variable that would contain the desired XPath string):

```
document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
```

This has worked fine in the JavascriptExecutor for all XPaths except for one case:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("example.com");
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String xpath = "(//div[@class='aclass']//a)[2]";
String javascript = "return document.evaluate(arguments[0], document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue";
WebElement element = js.executeScript(javascript, xpath);
element.click();
```

The same xpath used above works in the browser console, but not in the JavascriptExecutor. Note the "[2]". If the index value is "[1]", it works in JavascriptExecutor; but any value higher than that does not work (e.g. "[2]", "[3]", "[4]", "[5]", etc.). In the browser console these work fine.

So my question is, **"why doesn't this Javascript code, that clearly works in the browser console, work in the JavascriptExecutor?"**

The scenario of my DOM is that I have 6 `<a>` elements that have the same parent element `<div class='aclass'>`. The Javascript returns each of the 6 elements correctly in the browser console respective to its index with the XPath `"(//div[@class='aclass']//a)[index]"`, but only the first element returns correctly in the JavascriptExecutor while the others return null.

Comment: Also, this is not a timing issue. My code looks for elements every 500 milliseconds multiple times until the element is found or a certain number of attempts have failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is that I wasn't instantiating a new JavascriptExecutor after executing the first. Each subsequent use of the JavascriptExecutor fails unless you instantiate a new instance.